# NOT IN not working MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying with search query to make search function on my site, but I don't want get `films` that have `contestId='-1'`.

Here is my query for search:

```
SELECT * FROM film WHERE  MATCH (title, otherInfo, inspiration, description,directedBy,
keywords,producer) AGAINST ('$searchresults' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE )
and contestId not in (select contest_id from contest where contest_id !='-1' ) 
OR title LIKE 'ho%' OR title LIKE '%ho' and isApproved=1 order by film_id desc limit 1
```

Still getting result with `contestId='-1'`.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want films that have `contestId='-1'`, then shouldn't it be `... and contestId IN (select contest_id from contest where contest_id !='-1' ) ...` **or** `... and contestId NOT IN (select contest_id from contest where contest_id ='-1' ) ...`?

Comment: Still getting same results

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `WHERE contestId != '-1'` or `contestId NOT IN('-1')`?

Comment: i have tried this, i think anything with and condition not working, i have excluded the film_id that was coming but even then the film is showing, any suggestions?

Comment: I think your issue is the `OR` -> `AND contestId NOT IN (... ) OR title LIKE 'ho%' OR title LIKE '%ho' ...`. You need to change to an `AND` or use parenthesis to clarify the `AND`/`OR` preference

Comment: can you please explain the query.

Comment: Try this one. `SELECT * FROM film WHERE  MATCH (title, otherInfo, inspiration, description,directedBy,
keywords,producer) AGAINST ('$searchresults' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE )
and contestId not in (select contest_id from contest where contest_id ='-1' ) 
AND (title LIKE 'ho%' OR title LIKE '%ho') and isApproved=1 order by film_id desc limit 1`

Comment: Thanks @Sean , it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   *
FROM     film
WHERE    MATCH (title, otherinfo, inspiration, description,directedby, keywords,producer) against ('$searchresults' IN NATURAL language mode )
AND      contestid NOT IN
         (
                SELECT contest_id
                FROM   contest
                WHERE  contest_id ='-1' )
AND     (
                  title LIKE 'ho%'
         OR       title LIKE '%ho' )
AND      isapproved=1
ORDER BY film_id DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Couple of Errors

- `SELECT contest_id FROM contest WHERE contest_id !='-1'` Should be `SELECT contest_id FROM contest WHERE contest_id ='-1'`.
- `AND contestId NOT IN (... ) OR title LIKE 'ho%' OR title LIKE '%ho' ....` Will include records even if there have `contestId = -1`.  `title LIKE 'ho%' OR title LIKE '%ho'` should be wrapped inside AND. like `AND (title LIKE 'ho%' OR title LIKE '%ho')`